# Detect if cell is Currency format

Tags: php, parsing, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I have a PHP application that parses Excel files. It reads every cell from Excel so given that it might read dates, int/number, currency, string, etc.

Can I detect if the format of a currency cell?  For example, I can detect the date as follows:

`$cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
 $isdate = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell);`

and I'd like something like this:

`$iscurrency = PHPExcel_SOMETHING_DETECTCURRENCY($cell)`

Comment: `currency format` -- could you provide values of this format?

Comment: Possibilities are
€ 500 ,
$ 500

or so

Comment: currency sign + number?

Comment: @sangoku do you have problem in reading or detecting?

Comment: @Mobasher its detecting

Comment: @sectus yes, base on excel formatting of currency. All i want is to detect the cell if its on currency or date or int or string. 
For example in excel content:
A1 has 10/21/2014,
B1 has 1234,
C1 has $500,
D1 has 'Total' so its A1=date,B1=int,C1=currency,D1=string